# Changing "Region format" in Windows programatically (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, regional-settings

In Windows you have this window where you can set which format you want on your date and time (and currencies if you click "Additional Settings").

How do you change this programatically?

I have already found links telling me to set it using the `CultureInfo` classes. This is not a good solution as this will only set it for one application, not the entire system.

I've found promising links pointing to `HKCurrentUser\ControlPanel\Internaltional` where I can see many of these settings, but from what I've read, changing settings in the registry requires a reboot of the computer. Setting the values directly in the window screenshot below does *not* require a reboot.

When I do an actual update in the window screenshot below I can see that most of the values in the registry changes. If I am to do that programatically it seems a bit overkill to need to change all of them when I just select one item from the combobox.

Surely there's a better way, i.e. Windows API Calls (which also lets me handle the "Additional Settings")?

[image: Region format window]

Comment: There is an undocumented API available for OEM installation builder NlsUpdateSystemLocale() part of [kernel32.dll]. I doubt it is exposed in .Net framework as it's too native to the system. You can look at it. I've used it from C programs and it behaves as the dialog in your post. Can I ask your use case?

Comment: I'm doubt you're going to find a nice way of doing this, since it's a setting for the user, not applications. Applications should avoid changing the global user configuration of the system. Of course, noöne can prevent you from reverse-engineering the window and doing the same thing (it's not a priviledged application), but you'll be stuck having to do ugly P/Invokes and making sure it works in every version of Windows (since it's not a public, documented API). I assume you're doing this to work around broken applications, but in general, it's none of your application's business.

Comment: @i.net My use case is that we have a suite of applications that sort of "replaces" Windows. Instead of setting datetime/currency formats directly in each application we have found that setting the correct formats in Windows makes all our applications just work. So if our setup application could change the Windows settings, it would save us a LOT of work not having to adapt every application. I'll definitely look into that API tomorrow.

Comment: `...Instead of setting datetime/currency formats directly in each application...` Can't you just change it for the user so that all applications invoked by the user uses the new format?

Comment: @i.net Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. That is what changing the setting in Windows does.

Comment: Look at SetLocaleInfo Windows API function in that case. Not sure if this is in .Net (I doubt it).

Answer (score 0):

In powershell 3, was introduced Get-Culture and Set-Culture cmdlets. I am sure, it work from Win 8, I am not sure about Win 7 and Vista. 
In powershell you can change user regional settings like this:

```
$culture = Get-Culture
$culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = 'yyyy-MM-dd'
$culture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = 'dddd, d MMMM, yyyy'
$culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = 'h:mm tt'
$culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = 'h:mm:ss tt'
$culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ":"
Set-Culture $culture
```

You can find other options by executing $culture | get-member , 
 $culture.DateTimeFormat | Get-Member,
 $culture.NumberFormat | Get-Member

You can very easy host powershell script in your c# application. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706563(v=vs.85).aspx